# Master-Detail Template not working on my project

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried integrating a Master-Detail Template to my application but the app crashes when I tap the Add button.

What I did is:

- Created a class named `InfoTableViewController`, subclass of `UITableViewController` and copy all the contents of `MasterViewController` to my class.
- Created an UITableView in my Storyboard and assigned the class `InfoTableViewController` to the Table View.

I have made sure that the code is exactly the same as the one on the sample template, but it crashes whenever I try tapping the + button.

I get the following error log when the app crashes. Have I missed something? I don`t understand why my code does not work and the code in the template does.

`2014-08-12 12:16:11.496 Abonos[2591:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:1175
2014-08-12 12:16:11.501 Abonos[2591:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 sections after the update'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are returning 0 (zero) on `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` method. Try to return 1 in that method. And also, be sure to update the data source (array/dictionary that contains rows information) before you insert new row or update table. Good Luck!

Comment: That did not work, instead, i got a different error log ``2014-08-12 13:00:45.693 Abonos[2781:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:5439
2014-08-12 13:00:45.699 Abonos[2781:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'``

Comment: The error is clear enough to fix. I recommend you reading some basic table programming on iOS/Objective-C

Comment: If you go to Xcode and you create a new project, select ``Master - Detail Application`` and you will check that ``MasterViewController.m`` has ``- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`` method returning 0. Why in my project I need to change the value for an error to go? Thanks for your help.